# Improvement relationships

Tags: laravel, view, attributes, entity, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to make Entity Attribute Value system in my project. I'm working in Laravel.

What I'm trying to do is:

Products, eq. Car can have many attributes,

Product: Car
Color: Red, Green, Blue
Type: Hatchback, Sedan

I need to make good relations in my datatbase. My database:

```
products
=========
id | title   | description | Price
--------------------------------------------
1  | Audi    |     Car     | 2500

attributes
==========
id | name
----------
1  | Color

attribute_values
=================
id | attribute_id | value
--------------------------
1  |       1      | Blue
2  |       1      | Green

product_attribute
=================
id | product_id | attribute_id | value_id
-------------------------------------------
1  |     1      |      1       |    1 
2  |     1      |      1       |    2
```

My relations

Product:

```
public function attributes(){
            return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
```

Attribute:

```
public function values(){
       return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

Product_Attribute:

```
public function attribute(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id');
}
public function value(){
     return $this->belongsTo(AttributeValue::class, 'value_id');
}
```

And my function to show all offer with values:

```
$x = Product::find(1);
    foreach($x->attributes as $attr){
        echo $attr->attribute->name;
        foreach($attr->attribute->values as $att){
            echo $att->value;
        }
    }
```

What I get:

Color: Blue, Green 
Color: Blue, Green

Why the hell is it twice?!

Comment: why do you need  attribute_id in attribute_values table

Comment: I would approach it differently... although this database structure could make sense, I find it way to complicated... thing of the query/speed/resources required to get all the blue cars... Now all cars have a color, there is no fault in having the color as an attribute in the CAR table... Think about how will this data be accessed, start with the queries and don't create hell for yourself...

Comment: Any examples? I'm fighting with it more than 2 weeks. I have no idea how to make it work.